# Why this program involving thread returns "Yes" first

Tags: java

When I run the following code, it returns Yes followed by 9 No. But I thought it should be 10 No, because the start() will execute the run segment, which set the mysting to No, isn't it? Please help explain. Thanks!

```
class myThread implements Runnable{

String mystring = "Yes ";

public void run() {

this.mystring = "No ";

}

public static void main (String args[]) {

myThread t = new myThread();
new Thread(t).start();

for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

    System.out.println(t.mystring);
}

}

}
```

Comment: You start the Thread but you don't know how on when it's being executed. Sometimes you will get 10 No and other times you could get 2 Yes or more.

Comment: There is no thread safety here at all; your results will be completely undefined.  It's not guaranteed that `No` will ever show up, I believe, because your String reference is not `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are used for parallel execution. This means the code of the Thread runs parallel to the one of the `main`-Method. But there's no guarantee about the order of execution. Which is exactly what you experience here. The code in `main` is slightly faster than the start-up of the `Thread` and thus the first output is "yes".